# Getting this oracle error message: PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors

I am working on this for my homework. When I run it, I get the error:

```
PACKAGE PKG_Q4 Compiled.
 Warning: execution completed with warning
 PACKAGE BODY PKG_Q4 Compiled.
 50/12          PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name.
```

I've looked into this but I cant seem to find a way to fix it. It is pointing to this line:

```
INTO v_Room_Number, v_Pet_Status, v_Customer_Source_Description, v_Invoice_Total
```

Here is my code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_Q4 
    AS
      FUNCTION FN_Q4
        (p_First_Name VARCHAR2, p_Last_Name VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2 
        AS
        v_Output VARCHAR2(500);
        v_Room_Number NUMBER(3,0);
        v_Pet_Status CHAR(1);
        v_Customer_Source_Description VARCHAR2(30);
        v_Invoice_Total NUMBER(7,2);
        v_First_Name VARCHAR2(15);
        v_Last_Name VARCHAR2(20);
        v_Customer_Code CHAR(4);
        v_Registration_Status_Code CHAR(1);


        BEGIN

          SELECT First_Name, Last_Name
          INTO v_First_Name, v_Last_Name
          FROM Customer
          WHERE First_Name = p_First_Name AND
                Last_Name = p_Last_Name;




          Select Registration_Status_Code
          INTO v_Registration_Status_Code
          FROM Registration_Status;






          IF v_Registration_Status_Code = 'N' THEN
            SELECT Room.Room_Number, Room.Pet_Status, Customer_Source.Customer_Source_Description, Invoice.Invoice_Total
            INTO v_Room_Number, v_Pet_Status, v_Customer_Source_Description, v_Invoice_Total
            FROM Registration , Customer , Customer_Source , Room , Invoice 
            WHERE Customer.customer_code = Registration.customer_code AND
                  Customer_Source.customer_source_code = Customer.customer_source_code AND
                  Room.room_number = Registration.room_number AND
                  Registration.registration_number = Invoice.registration_number;
                v_Output := 'Room Number:' || v_Room_Number ||'Pet Status:' || v_Pet_Status ||
                            'Customer Source Code:' || v_Customer_Source_Description ||'Total Cost:' || v_Invoice_Total;

         END IF;
Return Varchar2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd wager the problem is actually this line, at the very bottom of the code excerpt:

```
Return Varchar2;
```

"Varchar2" is a type, you can't use it as the argument of a RETURN statement.  In the function declaration, `RETURN VARCHAR2` is correct usage, indicating the type of the value returned by the function.  The actual RETURN statement should return a value of that type, like

```
RETURN 'This is a string literal';
```

In your case, I'm guessing you want:

```
RETURN v_Output;
```